# Add context to same translatable strings

Tags: feature-request, bug, localization, traducir

Before today I thought that if the Transifex/traducir database contains the same original strings, they must have an additional **different** context (or/and plural values) field on which people can make the right translations.

But for now I see the same original sentences, e.g. ["$count$ views"](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5C%24count%5C%24%20views) without context information:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17268

  > [image: 17268]
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17494

  > [image: 17494]

If that is now possible with Transifex/traducir we definitely need to have the context information to make the right translations.

Comment: Do you have an (authoritative) reference for traducir?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum what kind of reference do you mean?

Comment: A web page that describes what it is. Or perhaps some published paper.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum maybe this [one](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir).

Comment: That will do. Thanks. Is "traducir.win" the full name of it? Or just the URL for the web site?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum as far as I know that is the full name. But better ask to [@g3rv4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/238921/g3rv4)